# How to call API class in a ASP.NET CORE WEB APP (MVC) Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I created an ASP.NET Core MVC web app project in VS19, I created an API controller that has a function that I typically would be able to access when its in an ASP.NET Core Web API (swagger).

However, I tried to go to `http:localhost:5001/api/GetAll/RLsOpHkBucbHZrU6lGk6` but it did not work so I removed the id and just left it as `GetAll` and it says page not found.

Is there a way to call an API controller in an ASP.NET Core MVC project since swagger isn't being used?

```
namespace CustomerSimulatorApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ESController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IElasticClient _elasticClient;

        public ESController(IElasticClient elasticClient)
        {
            _elasticClient = elasticClient;
        }

        [HttpGet("GetAll/{_id}")] 
        public async Task<EsSource> GetAll(String _id) // this will return everything within the source
        {
            var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<EsSource>(s => s
                                               .Source(true)
                                               .Index("customer-simulation-es-app-logs*")
                                               .Query(q => q.Match(m => m.Field("_id").Query(_id))));

           return response?.Documents?.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it is @mason

Comment: Sorry, so I created an entire MVC project but inside of the Controllers folder that contains other MVC Controllers, I have a API controller. Hope this makes sense... @mason

Comment: The reason why I created an API controller is because that will allow me to read the logs from Elasticsearch, which in that API controller the `GetAll()` method does what it needs to do. However, I am wanting to use that API controller within the MVC project. @mason

Comment: If I create a MVC controller instead of a API controller and put those exact code inside of the MVC controller, I'd have to create a View to display those logs. I don't want to do that. I will use Grafana to display the logs, I just want to be able to read the logs from elasticsearch. Unless I am wrong that I do not need to create a view for the ESController that is a MVC Controller instead of API controller @mason

Comment: @mason See the updated code. I run it on postman and this returns, I did it this way and am able to read it this way. But now I am wanting to know if I have to read it through postman or can I read it directly from the MVC Project (like the browser) not sure if this makes sense.

Comment: Postman is not doing anything special. It's just sending a crafted HTTP request to an endpoint and showing you the response. There's no reason you can't do that from a browser.

Comment: I see. so how would I call that method in the browser then? @mason

Comment: Grab URL. Paste into address bar. Press enter.

Comment: Wow I feel stupid, I was overthinking it! Thanks for your help and patience!